# Правильно ли расставлены запятые и тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

*На этапе предварительной загрузки, — если ошибок нет, — строка не выделяется.*

Верно ли я написал? Если да, то почему, если нет, то тоже почему?
Благодарю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите предложение полностью.

Comment: Здесь лучше использовать скобки.

Comment: просто запятые, так как это последовательность действий, тире тут не нужны, тире это про "а если подумать" или про разорванные действия по времени, месту и тп. Ну или в крайнем случае: на этапе предварительной загрузки, если ошибок нет - строка не выделяется.  Если принципиально, что строка не выделяется относится одинаково к первой и второй части.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что запятые при *вставочном оформлении* не нужны, потому что их нет ни в "разорванном" предложении, ни во вставке.

Нашелся и похожий "пример от классика":
*Здесь своеволие в почете,

Но строго властвует закон,

И **— если нет ошибки в счете —**

Послушно все выходят вон…*
Борис Заходер. [Считалия](https://azbyka.ru/fiction/veselye-stihi-boris-zahoder/4/)

Также, думаю, стоит прислушаться к мнению, изложенному в ПАС:

> Примечание 2. При оформлении вставных конструкций в середине предложения встречается употребление **запятой и тире** как единого знака препинания: *Вы садитесь в коляску, — **это так приятно после вагона**, — и катите по степной дороге* (Ч.). Такое выделение для современных текстов не характерно.

[Знаки препинания при вставках](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128) (§ 97)

Comment: В аналогичном параграфе Розенталя тоже есть пример с "если": *…Даже мои хозяева — **если они были дома** — открывали окна и, слушая, хвалили музыканта* (М. Г.).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр. Ну да, я тоже видела это предложение у Розенталя. Просто такая ссылка уже есть, а мне хотелось *наповыцарапать* что-нибудь  другое.

Comment: В ПАС же не мнение, там надёжная информация.

Comment: Насчёт вашего глагола "наповыцарапать": "по" же не используется вместе с совершенной формой, например, нельзя сказать "повымесить", "понайти". "По", когда продолжительное действие. То есть надо "наповыцарапывать". Верно? А то режет слух.

Comment: И курсивом выделяются примеры (как надо сказать, как надо написать и т.п.), курсив нельзя вместо кавычек, когда нестандартное употребление слова и когда придуманное слово. Вроде бы это уже говорил.

Comment: Не обижайтесь, что получилось так много мелких замечаний. Все указания на ошибки делают нас умнее.

Answer (score -1):

**Мой ответ** (взамен удаленного, который был дан **раньше других**)

Такое оформление возможно: *На этапе предварительной загрузки, **— если ошибок нет,** — строка не выделяется.*

Сравнить (вариант без тире): *На этапе предварительной загрузки, **если ошибок нет,** строка не выделяется.*

Такая запись тоже возможна, но придаточное **не будет выделено.**

**Пояснение**

Предложение (**сложноподчиненное**) в такой записи не выглядит стандартно, но и этот вариант можно объяснить правилами. Тогда считаем, что здесь придаточное предложение оформлено **как вставка.**

Это тема Розенталь, § 26. Вводные и вставные конструкции, пункт 4(4)

В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной конструкции на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, помимо тире, могут быть еще запятые. Здесь возможны следующие случаи: 4) как перед первым, так и перед вторым тире ставится запятая по условиям текста.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Я не хотела применять **несимметричную постановку запятых**, так как можно считать, что придаточное  (вставка)  относится **ко всему предложению**. Сравнить: *На этапе предварительной загрузки строка не выделяется, **если ошибок нет**.*

**Вариант без запятых**  возможен, но запись придаточного предложения выглядит хуже (это авторский выбор): *На этапе предварительной загрузки — **если ошибок нет** — строка не выделяется.*

**ВЫВОД**

Таким образом, у задачи **несколько ПРАВИЛЬНЫХ решений**. Каждое из них имеет определенные  **преимущества и недостатки** с точки зрения **семантики** (обозначения отнесенности придаточного к нужной части предложения), выбора **графического** оформления, а также возможности универсального и быстрого **доказательства** без лишних дискуссий, если это требуется.

**Мои комментарии (деловое **ОБСУЖДЕНИЕ** темы)**

(Кстати, здесь именно я предлагаю оформление придаточного предложения **в виде вставки, а потом говорю, что запятые можно убрать)**

Есть еще **симметричная постановка знаков.** Она сюда вполне подходит. Вставка как бы относится ко всему сообщению.

Тогда это последний абзац этого пункта, а не начало, которое вы цитируете. Но там тоже одна запятая обязательна по условиям текста, а другая ставится просто для симметрии.

В том-то и дело. А вы сами ответьте, если смысл сообщения лучше понимаете. В конце концов **можно ОБЕ ЗАПЯТЫЕ УБРАТЬ (на месте разрыва нет знаков)**. Но это все-таки **придаточное**, так что с запятыми красивее. –

Если бы я видела **контекст** и понимала бы ситуацию, то сказала бы точно, что подходит. А сейчас я просто выбрала подходящую форму и более или менее подходящее объяснение. Эта тема вообще смутная с точки зрения **интонации.** С одной стороны, вставочная интонация, а с другой — как на это влияют запятые? Вот с симметричным вариантом все понято (две запятые не влияют никак).

**А это КРИТИКА в мой адрес**

Под моим ответом, где можно предлагать улучшение и уточнение. Доброжелательная такая критика...

*У вас нет права писать неправду! **Это не форум, здесь место только правильным ответам!**  Ещё раз: у вас нет права писать неправду!*

*А почему **вы плюёте** на то, что вам говорят? Почему плюёте на то, что сказал Александр? Да потому что **вам всё равно, правильный ответ или нет!** Считаю, что это больше всего заслуживает дизлайка. Нежелание исправлять — это просто ужасно!
Александр просил исправить, а вы ничего не сделали! **Вы тупо на всё плюёте.** А потом негодуете, что только вас все критикуют. –*

*Ну вот по правилам сайта. Уточните в ответе, почему две запятые. По условиям контекста ни одна запятая не требуется, так как в предложении "На этапе предварительной загрузки строка не выделяется" **нет запятых**.*

*Вам лучше отвечать на mail.ru, где неправильных ответов больше, чем правильных. Здесь нужны **ТОЛЬКО ПРАВИЛЬНЫЕ ответы и люди,** которые желают становиться лучше и исправлять. Или лучше искусством заняться, например рисованием. Вы же художник в душе... Люди на вас рассчитывают, **надеются, а вы им врёте**... А потом у них из-за вас большие проблемы (оказалось, что написали неправильно). А вы считаете, что нет последствий.*

**Мой ответ на критику**

*Уважаемый участник! Хочу напомнить вам, что форум  — это не место, куда приходят **за верой.** Русский язык — это сайт вопросов и ответов **ДЛЯ ЛИНГВИСТОВ** и энтузиастов русского языка, где **ОБСУЖДАЮТСЯ** сложные вопросы языкознания и новые технологии в языке. Мы также **не выполняем домашние задания** и всё, что на них похоже.*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147174/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.